# Cursor Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a function to move an element from one div to another and work very well, but when i drag element the cursor change to `cursor: not-allowed;` or something similar, but I want change cursor to `cursor: grab;` when i move the element, how i can do this?

Is the same example of this question: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73533981/background-parent-element-drag-and-drop-div/73534399#73534399)

I try:

```
#piece:focus{
cursor: grab;
}
#piece:selection{
cursor: grab;
}
#piece:hover{
cursor: grab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, in `dragStart`, add `e.target.classList.add('grabbed');` and in `dragEnd`, add `e.target.classList.remove('grabbed');`.

Then add css `.grabbed { cursor: grab; }`.

Comment: unfortunately when I drag the element it remains the same

Comment: When I drag the dog picture in the other question you reference, my cursor remains a normal pointer type cursor throughout (before, during, and after the drag). When exactly are you seeing the not allowed cursor appear? Can you update your question to demonstrate the problem?